Comparing dates and return filtered results
i have the below code that compares a date column with a given date and i am expecting to get an output when condition is met,i.e date in date column comes after given date. Any help in this would be appreciated.Thanks
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_excel('test_date.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')
start_date = pd.Timestamp(2024, 5, 1)
filtered_date = df1.loc[df1['date'] > start_date]
filtered_date.to_csv("filtered.csv",index=False)

input file:

Code to generate input as dataframe
import pandas as pd

data = {'serial': [10037, 10140, 10167, 10173, 10175, 10184, 10187],
        'date': ['28/05/2020 00:00', '14/09/2021 00:00', '27/05/2023 00:00',
                 '15/05/2024 00:00', '21/07/2024 00:00', '21/07/2024 00:00',
                 '19/06/2024 00:00']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

output expected:


What is the output you get?

Code
At first convert your date column to datetime dtype and then make condition & filter.
# from your code
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_excel('test_date.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')

# edit your code
date = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', errors='coerce') 
filtered_date = df1.loc[date > pd.Timestamp(2024, 5, 1)]

# from your code
filtered_date.to_csv("filtered.csv",index=False)

errors='coerce' is not necessary if all your data can be converted to datetime, but I added it because often not.

You can check this code with the code below.
import pandas as pd

data = {'serial': [10037, 10140, 10167, 10173, 10175, 10184, 10187],
        'date': ['28/05/2020 00:00', '14/09/2021 00:00', '27/05/2023 00:00',
                 '15/05/2024 00:00', '21/07/2024 00:00', '21/07/2024 00:00',
                 '19/06/2024 00:00']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df1)

date = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', errors='coerce') 
filtered_date = df1.loc[date > pd.Timestamp(2024, 5, 1)]

print(filtered_date)


Thanks, getting the below error:
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "DatetimeArray") to str

@syed I don't think the error is caused by the code I suggested - my code doesn't concat datetime and str.

@syed i update my answer for you to check my code.

Thanks. your code works. the issue I have is when I read in the xlsx file that
i use has a date column. The data type of the date is String with format dd/mm/yyyy. i think i need to convert that string to date format so i can do the filtering
